# SplitString or SubString or?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is there (.NET 3.5 and above) already a method to split a string like this:

- string str = "{MyValue} something else {MyOtherValue}"
- result: MyValue , MyOtherValue

Comment: You want to grab placeholders within braces?

Comment: Use Regular Expressions class.

Comment: Yes I want to get the values (represents strings) within the braces.

Comment: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._

Comment: Can `MyValue` and `MyOtherValue` contain brackets?

Comment: @BradChristie http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html That quote is very much abused...

Comment: @JustinPihony: I'm aware, I just see people jump to regex an awful lot on this site. `if (question.Contains("string")) { return Regex }` appears to be the standard answer format. I alo feel there's a lack of context in the question (what characters can be within the braces, what are some examples of strings that should be parsed, will this be done on small or large scale, ...). Things that I feel should be answered before coming to the regex solution.

Comment: @BradChristie excellent point.  To generalize for any solution, not just regex solutions: A solution that gives correct results with sample data could nonetheless give incorrect results for some of the real data.

Comment: @BradChristie - then please show us how to tackle _this_ problem w/o Regex. A brief outline will do.

Comment: @BradChristie Then you should ask those clarifying questions rather than spout off a quote that is supposed to imply those questions?

Comment: @JustinPihony: I was getting there, until you made a comment and I got side-tracked. Also, by that time people had posted 3 alternative regex solution to the answer and I lost momentum, TBH. Henk: Parse it myself? Inevitably iterating over the string myself and finding matches is less intense that spinning up a regex library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like:

```
        string regularExpressionPattern = @"\{(.*?)\}";
        Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

dont forget to add new namespace: [System.Text.RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx);

Comment: Went in originally for spelling on "Expressins", but then thought a reference for the OP was useful. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to do it. This fragment prints `MyValue` and `MyOtherValue`.

```
var r = new Regex("{([^}]*)}");
var str = "{MyValue} something else {MyOtherValue}";
foreach (Match g in r.Matches(str)) {
    var s = g.Groups[1].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
string []result = "{MyValue} something else {MyOtherValue}".
           Split(new char[]{'{','}'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

string myValue = result[0];
string myOtherValue = result[2];
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for indexes [`0` & `2`](http://ideone.com/GNXzW) not `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(str, @"\{([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(match[0] + "," + match[1]);
```